# Code work, but log says "Missing argument 3"

Tags: php, magento

I use this code to show short description on my product page in Magento.

```
<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getShortDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_description, 'short_description')) ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In my systemlog it says:
Warning: Missing argument 3 for Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output::productAttribute() on line 4

But the page work fine. However i can't really see where the error are.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', 1); add these two to your code

Comment: productAttribute(`$this->getProduct()`, `nl2br($_description, 'short_description')`) It looks like you are only passing two arguments into this function and it wants 3. It is just a warning so it may have a default argument.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, you set the parenthesis wrong. `'short_description'` belongs not to `nl2br` - it belongs to the `productAttribute()` call.

```
    echo $this->helper('catalog/output')
              ->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_description), 'short_description');
```

This error occurs, because your calling a function, which expects three params and only passing two params. As the third param has no default value, php prints a warning about the missing thrid param.
Because you run magento in production mode, the warning is never printed to the user and just written to `var/log/system.log`